# Issue with the Navigation Click Handler - JETPACK - KOTLIN

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack, android-navigation-graph

I am using the Navigation functionality of the JetPack library.

Included Two Fragments in Navigation Graph.

Have to navigate from `TitleFragment` to `GameFragment` with the click of the button which is inside TitleFragment.

I have done as below inside TitleFragment to take the click of that button :

```
binding.playButton.setOnClickListener {
        Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.action_titleFragment_to_gameFragment)
        //Navigation.findNavController(it).navigate(R.id.gameFragment)
    }
```

where `action_titleFragment_to_gameFragment` is action id.

Used `createNavigateOnClickListener` method but its not working. Instead commented the second line is working.

What might be the issue with `Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.action_titleFragment_to_gameFragment)`

Content of Navigation Graph is as below :

```
 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/titleFragment"
    android:name="com.example.android.navigation.TitleFragment"
    android:label="fragment_title"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_title" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_titleFragment_to_gameFragment"
        app:destination="@id/gameFragment" />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/gameFragment"
    android:name="com.example.android.navigation.GameFragment"
    android:label="fragment_game"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_game" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a clicklistener on a view in android by following two patterns,

- By passing an instance of a class implementing `View.OnClickListener` where you override the `OnClick` method
- Since `View.OnClickListener` is a SAM, you can pass a `lambda` instead of implementing the `View.OnClickListener` interface.

`button.setOnClickListener{ ... }` expecting a lambda and `button.setOnClickListener( ... )` expects an instance of `View.OnClickListener`.

So in your case, since `Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener` returns  object of type `View.OnClickListener` use `round brackets - ()` and **not** `curly brackets - {}`